# if Operator in PHP not working as it should be

Tags: php, string

I am fetching data from excel file in php there is a field data written (Emp. Code ) when i match as it is same in php if condition like this

```
if($Dt2 == "Emp. Code ")
```

its not working

but i tried also to trim and replace (.) and (space) with nothing. like

```
$Data2 = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$RNo][3];
$Dt2 = str_replace(".","",str_replace(" ","",trim(strtolower(trim($Data2)))));
```

when i echo it shows

```
(empcode)
```

so i write code of match with this string also like

```
if($Dt2 == "empcode")
```

its also not working in this condition

example code is below for reference

```
    $Data2 = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$RNo][3];
    $Dt2 = str_replace(".","",str_replace(" ","",trim(strtolower(trim($Data2)))));
    if($Dt2 == "empcode")
    {
      $EmployeeCode = $Data5;
      $EmployeeName = $Data28;

      echo "============================ Employee Name : <b>$EmployeeName ($EmployeeCode)</b> ========================<br /><hr />";

      $LastEmployeeCode = $EmployeeCode;
    }
    else
    {
      echo "NOT MATCHED >>> Checked : (<b>$Dt2</b>) with (<b>empcode</b>)<br /><hr />";
    }
```

it always went into else condition. Please suggest where i am wrong.. this is a very strange case i can't understand..

Comment: does it echo `(empcode)` or `empcode` ? does it have round brackets? also try `var_dump($Data2);` before the if statement and put the result here

Comment: Are you positive those are actual latin characters and that there's no extraneous (invisible) byte in the string? Because it should definitely work as it is.

Comment: `$Dt2 == ????` please share, or try with `$Dt2 === "empcode"`

Comment: `$Dt2 = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9$]/i","",$Data2));` will remove everything that isn't an alpha-numeric character in your string, which might help your comparison/if case use.

Comment: Dear all, I don't know what happened with that code as it was seen perfect but i closed excel file and php fle and then re-open them and it start working. well thanks all for your support and suggesiton really appreciated Oras, Federico, devpro & Jason thanks alot guys